# How to configure apache 2.2 as load balancer to manage tomcat instances running javascript application

Tags: javascript, load-balancing, apache2.2

I have installed apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (# apt-get install -y -q apache2).
I have tow tomcat instances in which I have deployed a war application running javascript.

```
The apacheLB IP is: http://public_ip:80/app
The tomcat applications private url are: http://177.86.0.115:80/app and http://177.86.0.116:80/app
```

I have enabled the following modules as follow:

```
pushd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled 
sudo ln -f -s ../mods-available/proxy_balancer.conf proxy_balancer.conf 
sudo ln -f -s ../mods-available/proxy_balancer.load proxy_balancer.load 
sudo ln -f -s ../mods-available/proxy.conf proxy.conf 
sudo ln -f -s ../mods-available/proxy.load proxy.load 
sudo ln -f -s ../mods-available/proxy_http.load 
popd
```

I have configure proxy_balancer.conf as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_balancer.c>    
<IfModule mod_status.c>

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>    
BalancerMember http://177.86.0.115:80/app    
BalancerMember http://177.86.0.116:80/app    
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !    
ProxyPass /app balancer://mycluster

ProxyPassReverse /app balancer://mycluster    
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ balancer://mycluster/$1

<Location /balancer-manager>    
        SetHandler balancer-manager    
        Allow from all    
</Location>    
</IfModule>    
</IfModule>
```

If I connect via browser to the load balancer URL I can't view images.
In the developer tools of chrome, I view:

```
login;jsessionid=18D12D6A45D6BE7379FDDABD1A445A2B:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
login;jsessionid=133E61276DABF0CD328F9555FA941AD2:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
login;jsessionid=28F0F9AAE7A6A0931093B6B344D17266:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
login;jsessionid=679B3A919757EB4C9C8C82587ABD39EA:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.validate.js:1243 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
login;jsessionid=2BB3E3044205EB49C5745D0B2FA16F68:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
login;jsessionid=25502F3D232720E088AD939D3543B5D2:87 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
login;jsessionid=25502F3D232720E088AD939D3543B5D2:196 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks,
G.

Comment: in other words, you're assets aren't being routed properly. Does everything else work, just not static assets?

Comment: Yes, it does. For example, I am able to log into the application through the load balancer, but I see that menu are listed instead of shown as images.

Answer (score 0):

I have done these steps:

1. connect to the application URL running on the balanced instances: es. `http://public_IP/app/login`
2. Clicking F12 on the Chrome browser and clicking on Network: I can see that the application  generates a Cookie:JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxx in the Request Header.
3. connect to the load balancer URL: es. `http://public_ip_load_balancer/app/login`
4. Clicking F12 on the Chrome browser and clicking on Network: I can see that the web page have not an JSESSIONID header, whereas I can see the the JSESSIONID is attached at the and of all the URL resource.

In other words, analizing the sorce code of the load balancer web page, I see:

```
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/app/resources/img/img.png;jsessionid=71CFE3AB5E3BAEF5187AE123E79C052D" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="/app/resources/img/img.png;jsessionid=71CFE3AB5E3BAEF5187AE123E79C052D">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/resources/css/foundation.css;jsessionid=71CFE3AB5E3BAEF5187AE123E79C052D" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/resources/css/app.css;jsessionid=71CFE3AB5E3BAEF5187AE123E79C052D" />
```

while analizing the sorce code of the application web page, I see:

```
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/app/resources/img/img.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="/app/resources/img/img.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/resources/css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/resources/css/app.css" />
```

I don't know why this happens.